# Combining multiple rules on multiple columns to get a composite result not behaving as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe like below:

```
PayeeId transactionId   createdAt                          Amount   Max_90D
100AA       60a23a1     2021-07-24 15:02:25.428000+05:30    5000      12000
100AA       60a23b1d    2021-07-24 20:37:04.351000+05:30    6650      12000 
100AA       60b4b69     2021-07-24 15:02:25.428000+05:30    3334      12000
100AA       6098eb81    2021-07-24 23:30:25.428000+05:30    1000      12000
```

I am trying to check the following conditions:

```
1. If any of the transaction amount ('Amount') is less than 5000, then df['Rule_No'] = 0
2. If condition 1 is not satisfied (as is this case) then
   2.a - Check which transaction time ('createdAt') is greater than 23:00 hrs and less than 08:00 hrs. If spotted then df['Rule_No'] = 6 
   2.b - If 2.a not satisfied find out if any transaction amount is > 1.5 times of Max_90D. 
   2.c - If yes then df['Rule_No'] = 6 else df['Rule_No'] = 0
```

So essentially the resultant dataframe will look like:

```
   PayeeId transactionId   createdAt                          Amount   Max_90D   Rule_No
    100AA       60a23a1     2021-07-24 15:02:25.428000+05:30    5000      12000     0
    100AA       60a23b1d    2021-07-24 20:37:04.351000+05:30    6650      12000     0
    100AA       60b4b69     2021-07-24 15:02:25.428000+05:30    3334      12000     0
    100AA       6098eb81    2021-07-24 23:30:25.428000+05:30    1000      12000     6
```

To accomplish this I am using the following:

```
if df['Amount'].any() < 50:
  df['Rule_No'] = 0
else:
  df['Rule_No'] = np.where((df['createdAt'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')<'08:00')|\
                         (df['createdAt'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')>'23:00')\
                         |(df['Amount'] > 1.5 * df['90D_Max']),6,0)
```

But it is not behaving as expected. Instead I am getting the original dataframe `df` with a column `Rule_No` as 0 for all 4 rows. In other words it is not entering the `else` block only.

Answer (score 0):

```
if df['Amount'].any() < 0:
    df['Rule_No'] = 0
else:
    if df['createdAt'].dt.strftime('%H:%M').any() < '08:00':
        df['Rule_No'] = 6

    else:
        res_df = df
        res_df['condition'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['Amount'] >= 1.5 * x['Max_90D'] else 0)
        if res_df['condition'].any() == 1:
            df['Rule_No'] = 6
        else:
            df['Rule_No'] = 0
```

Sorry for last answer, I hope this one will help you ;)

Comment: `df['Amount'].any()` is not working in my case. Have you tried the above in the sample I have given?

Comment: I have not tried your sample but in my case it's working. Good luck